# vue-cli-service build --target lib disable "use strict"

Tags: vue.js

IE11 does not work correctly with "use strict". But I do not know how to remove it, because I understand that this happens at the time of assembly. But I didn't find any answers in the vue documentation.
The command that I run: cross-env NODE_ENV=production vue-cli-service build --target lib --name testLib ./src/index.js --skip-plugins @vue/cli-plugin-eslint

I get an error in IE11:
Using multiple property definitions in strict mode is prohibited
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsd2R.png)

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: Which versions of Vue and Vue-CLI are you using?

Comment: This is probably user problem, e.g. https://forum.vuejs.org/t/multiple-definitions-of-property-not-allowed-in-strict-mode/103458 . You can try to clean up `use strict` from a bundle with some Webpack replacer plugin but looks like the last resort.

Comment: @EstusFlask i probably think there is get error from node_modules or dependencies. And its doesnt metter if IE11 not correct handle "use strict".

Comment: @Phil 
@vue/cli 4.5.13 vue@2.6.11 Also i added plugin: @babel/transform-strict-mode & add string in vue.config: transpileDependencies for my lib/plugin. But nothing works.